# Get image from desktop scanner powerapps

Tags: powerapps, scanning

I have an idea for an app to replace our current process for receiving orders from different departments via fax. I have some knowledge of powerapps, but not enough to build what I have in mind myself. Before I start looking for a professional developer, I first need to know if there is a way to make powerapps get the image from a desktop scanner like it does with cameras.
The outcome I am looking for is like that :user enters an order number in a text box, load the document then click a button on the app to start the scanning.
Now that I have a pdf file named with order number, powerapps can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If your scanner has a networking function, it's possible. Send the scan to a central server, let powerapps handle it and send it on as desired.